# Unhandled exception type using external library on Java Android

Tags: java, android, exception, marshalling, throwable

I'm doing a little class to save and load information from a game, by the moment I have coded this:

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;

import org.exolab.castor.xml.MarshalException;
import org.exolab.castor.xml.Marshaller;
import org.exolab.castor.xml.Unmarshaller;
import org.exolab.castor.xml.ValidationException;

class InformationToStoreLoad{
    public InformationToStoreLoad(){

    }
}

public class GameSaverLoader {

        /*
         * Save the current game
         */
        public void saveXML(){

            FileWriter writer;
            try {
                writer = new FileWriter("save.xml");
                Marshaller.marshal(new InformationToStoreLoad(), writer);
                writer.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

             /*
         * Load a game saved before
         */
        public void loadXML()
        {
            try {
                FileReader reader = new FileReader("article.xml");
                InformationToStoreLoad gameToLoad = 
                        (InformationToStoreLoad) Unmarshaller.unmarshal(InformationToStoreLoad.class, reader);
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
}
```

I have been working on .NET platforms and I'm a little bit noob with Java, so I'm not sure if I have done everything right. To export the Castor libraries I have right clicked on my project, I have selected Properties, then Java Build Path, then libraries, and finally I have clicked "Add external JAR" and I have exported this JAR: "castor-1.3.1-xml.jar"

However, I have the following error while using the marshaller and unmarshaller classes

```
Unhandled exception type ValidationException
```

If I select "Add catch clause to surrounding try" on quick fixes, then I get this errors instead:

```
No exception of type MarshalException can be thrown; an exception type must be a subclass of Throwable

The method printStackTrace() is undefined for the type MarshalException

No exception of type ValidationException can be thrown; an exception type must be a subclass of Throwable

The method printStackTrace() is undefined for the type ValidationException
```

Also in the quick fixes I have the option to make this:

```
public void saveXML() throws MarshalException, ValidationException{
```

then I get this error:

No exception of type MarshalException can be thrown; an exception type must be a subclass of Throwable

No exception of type ValidationException can be thrown; an exception type must be a subclass of Throwable

I don't know how to fix any of those errors, anyone can advise me how to solve this problems?

Best regards

Comment: So you get this error even at the line: `Marshaller.marshal(new InformationToStoreLoad(), writer);` ?

Comment: Yes, that's the thing :(